# Error after pass return function to class

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have this code I need to access variable from function to class. But after run, I see this error.

This is the code:

```
    class FirstClas():

        def get_number(self):
            number = 5
            return number

        print(get_number) # I need to print number outside function
```

I see this message:

```
<function FirstClas.get_path at 0x04340FA0>
```

Comment: `with open(...):` is not actually inside any method.

Comment: I add this code with open(...): in method but I need to pass variable from with open(...): to class. I try but same broblem

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean, but what you've posted certainly can't work. It seems to be a bit backwards, you're assigning to `path` based on the contents of the file at `path`?

Comment: This way is wrong, I Try to do another way

Comment: Did you mean to *call* `get_number` and print its return value?

Comment: Yes bro, I do this code print(get_path()) , but get error message : TypeError: get_path() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'